# App instantly crashing when attempting to store edittext values

Tags: android

I'm simply trying to store the values that the user inputs. Just storing the data in the variables causes my app to instantly crash before it even opens. I honestly don't know why this is happening.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


EditText StudentID;
EditText Name1;
EditText CStudy;
EditText Exam1;
EditText Exam2;
EditText Ass2;
EditText ass1;
EditText Examprog2;
Button save;

double studID = 0;
String SavedName = " ";
double CaseStudy = 0;
double Ex1 = 0;
double Ex2 = 0;
double assignment1 = 0;
double assignment2 = 0;
double prog2Exam = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    StudentID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.StudentID);

    Name1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Name1);
    CStudy = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.CStudy);
    Exam1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Exam1);
    Exam2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Exam2);
    ass1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ass1);
    Ass2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Ass2);
    Examprog2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Examprog2);

    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);

    String SavedName = Name1.getText().toString();
    double CaseStudy = Double.parseDouble(CStudy.getText().toString());
    double Ex1 = Double.parseDouble(Exam1.getText().toString());
    double Ex2 = Double.parseDouble(Exam2.getText().toString());
    double assignment1 = Double.parseDouble(ass1.getText().toString());
    double assignment2 = Double.parseDouble(Ass2.getText().toString());
    double prog2Exam = Double.parseDouble(Examprog2.getText().toString());
}
```

}

And the issue seems to be with this block of code

```
    String SavedName = Name1.getText().toString();
    double CaseStudy = Double.parseDouble(CStudy.getText().toString());
    double Ex1 = Double.parseDouble(Exam1.getText().toString());
    double Ex2 = Double.parseDouble(Exam2.getText().toString());
    double assignment1 = Double.parseDouble(ass1.getText().toString());
    double assignment2 = Double.parseDouble(Ass2.getText().toString());
    double prog2Exam = Double.parseDouble(Examprog2.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Can you post the exception stack trace you get?

Comment: what exactly error are show.. Show error

Comment: please post your exception stack trace!

Comment: I think you might be trying to parse NULL values. There is no way that the edittext's can be filled yet. Maybe create a button that the user can click after they have entered the values!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Double.parseDouble(CStudy.getText().toString())` I think,first time there are null value, so when you tried to parse null to Double, that's why its crashing.

So, you have to check condition like,

```
if(!CStudy.getText().toString().equals(""))
{
     Double.parseDouble(CStudy.getText().toString())
}
```

And add onClickListener of button like below code:

```
save.setOnClickListner(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String SavedName;
        double CaseStudy, Ex1, Ex2, assignment1,assignment2, prog2Exam;
        if(!Name1.getText().toString().equals(""))
            SavedName = Name1.getText().toString();
        if(!CStudy.getText().toString().equals(""))           
            CaseStudy = Double.parseDouble(CStudy.getText().toString());
        if(!Exam1.getText().toString().equals(""))           
            Ex1 = Double.parseDouble(Exam1.getText().toString());
        if(!Exam2.getText().toString().equals(""))           
            Ex2 = Double.parseDouble(Exam2.getText().toString());
        if(!ass1.getText().toString().equals(""))           
            assignment1 = Double.parseDouble(ass1.getText().toString());
        if(!Ass2.getText().toString().equals(""))           
            assignment2 = Double.parseDouble(Ass2.getText().toString());
        if(!Examprog2.getText().toString().equals(""))           
            prog2Exam = Double.parseDouble(Examprog2.getText().toString());
    }
});
```

Comment: Even better if you make a `Button` and attach a `onClickListener` and take a full control of WHEN you want to get the data from the user.

Comment: Yes sir, thank you for suggestion, I will change the answer.

Comment: Yup that did the trick. Thank you very much, appreciate the help and explanation.

Comment: hi sagar how are u ?

Comment: @GanpatKaliya, I am fine, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have to put the **value saving** codes inside your buttonclick listner

```
       save.setOnClickListner(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                String SavedName = Name1.getText().toString();
            try {
                double CaseStudy = Double.parseDouble(CStudy.getText().toString());
                double Ex1 = Double.parseDouble(Exam1.getText().toString());
                double Ex2 = Double.parseDouble(Exam2.getText().toString());
                double assignment1 = Double.parseDouble(ass1.getText().toString());
                double assignment2 = Double.parseDouble(Ass2.getText().toString());
                double prog2Exam = Double.parseDouble(Examprog2.getText().toString());
            } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
                //can't parse
            }
        }
    });
```

Otherwise you are parsing null/empty values then it may throw exception.

Also its better to wrap the parsing codes with a `try - catch`. Because it may throw `NumberFormatException` depending on the value

Answer (score 0):

> Just storing the data in the variables causes my app to instantly crash before it even opens.

You mentioned it crashed before it even opens, which mean there is no data in those `EditText` and you setting `NULL` value into the variables, this cause the error.

Answer (score 0):

You are parsing the values even before the user has a chance to full the edittext, which will cause a nullpointerexception. If you are trying the save the values after the user clicks the "save" button, try the following code:

```
save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            String SavedName = Name1.getText().toString();
            double CaseStudy = Double.parseDouble(CStudy.getText().toString());
            double Ex1 = Double.parseDouble(Exam1.getText().toString());
            double Ex2 = Double.parseDouble(Exam2.getText().toString());
            double assignment1 = Double.parseDouble(ass1.getText().toString());
            double assignment2 = Double.parseDouble(Ass2.getText().toString());
            double prog2Exam = Double.parseDouble(Examprog2.getText().toString());
       };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String SavedName = Name1.getText().toString();
    double CaseStudy = Double.parseDouble(CStudy.getText().toString());
    double Ex1 = Double.parseDouble(Exam1.getText().toString());
    double Ex2 = Double.parseDouble(Exam2.getText().toString());
    double assignment1 = Double.parseDouble(ass1.getText().toString());
    double assignment2 = Double.parseDouble(Ass2.getText().toString());
    double prog2Exam = Double.parseDouble(Examprog2.getText().toString());
```

This code should not be in the onCreate method. Just place this code on event of a button click.

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out, you are writing this code on OnCreate event, which is called on activity initialization. The EditText values would always be NULL at this point so no use writing the code there. You should place this code where you would save the data or do something with the data like on button click.